# Is there a way to infer periodicity of functions purely from their Taylor series?

Tags: calculus, power-series

I have been working with Taylor series for a while and I am interested in the following. Suppose I have the Maclaurin (for simplicity) series:

$f \left(x \right) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{a_{n}x^{n}}$

where the formula $a_{n} = g \left(n \right)$ is known. Furthermore, assume that the above series converges everywhere. Under these conditions, is it possible to deduce from $g \left(n \right)$ that $f \left(x \right)$ is periodic?

For instance, for $f \left(x \right) = \cos{\left(x \right)}$, $a_{2n} = \frac{\left(-1 \right)^{n}}{\left(2n \right)!}$ and $a_{2n + 1} = 0$ for $n \ge 0$. Does something about the "form" (for lack of a better word) of these coefficients imply the periodicity of $\cos{ \left(x \right)}$?

I have read in other questions on this site that if $g \left(n \right)$ is not known a priori, this is an undecidable problem: is this still the case when $g \left(n \right)$ is known?

As an aside, here is what I have tried: if $f \left(x \right)$ is periodic then one has $f \left(x \right) = f \left(x + P \right)$, where $P$ is the period and $P > 0$. Then, one has:

$f \left(x + P \right) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{a_{n} \left(x + P \right)^{n}}$

In particular, we have $f \left(0 \right) = f \left(P \right)$, giving:

$a_{0} = a_{0} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{a_{n}P^{n}}$

Giving $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{a_{n}P^{n}} = 0$

One can also differentiate $f \left(x \right)$, which yields:

$f' \left(x \right) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{n a_{n} x^{n - 1}}$

Requiring that $f' \left(x \right) = f' \left(x + P \right)$ and setting $x = 0$, one then has:

$a_{1} = a_{1} + \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}{n a_{n} P^{n - 1}}$

That is:

$\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}{n a_{n} P^{n - 1}} = 0$

The above procedure can be repeated ad infinitum for higher derivatives, which seems to give an infinite number of conditions which must be satisfied by the various $a_{n}$'s. However, it seems really complicated to deduce periodicity from these conditons. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I mean, the Maclaurin series determines the function completely, so if it is periodic, it is encoded in the Taylor coefficients. Or is your question really: Does there exist a real analytic function for which periodicity is undecidable? This seems like a hard logic problem, but your question doesn't really phrase it as such.

Comment: I doubt you could tell just from the Maclaurin series for $\sin x$ that it's a periodic function.

Comment: You would have to know not only that the series converges everywhere, but that it specifically converges to $f(x)$ everywhere. Consider the function $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x\neq0,$ $f(0)=0,$ and its Maclaurin series (or Taylor series at $x=0$).